# Lazy Load jQuery, custom trigger event

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, preload, lazy-loading

Is it possible to force Lazy Load to 'preload' an invisible image that is connected with the Lazy Load Plug-In? So that wehen the image get's visible, it's already loaded.

I've found only events that need an interaction like mouseover or click, but no event for my custom script that don't relies on user events.

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
event : "click"
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/476681/704894 Use the jQuery code posted there so you should be able to easily chain functions.

Comment: `$("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
    skip_invisible : false
});`

Comment: The `skip_invisible` parameter concerns only images which are hidden with css `display:none`. It has nothing to do with images which are outside viewport.

Answer (score -4):

Found a solution here:

http://sumanrs.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/jquery-lazy-loading-images-no-scrolling/

insert in your (e.g. click) function this:

```
$("img.lazy").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-original"));
   $(this).removeAttr("data-original");
});
```

Comment: This is totally wrong. Code above loads all images immediately and basically nullifies any positive effect Lazy Load plugin has. Lazy Loading is exact opposite of preloading. Lazy Loading means loading a resource only when it is needed. Preloading means loading a resource into cache before it is needed.